# MVC dynamic JQuery recieve dropdown value to feed HTML Helper that returns an image

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

Questions;
6164507
7869467 & 
3040342  have been very helpful BUT....
In .NET MVC C# 
I am trying to harvest a value from a dropdown and pass that value to my html helper which renders an
image in a div.  The questions cited above got me as far as this JdFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/276/

I'm pretty sure I can't place the selected option value in a var and pass it to the HTML Helper.
( different languages in the same viewpage  = Krazy !!) 
So I guess all I''m asking is how to get the value to the HTML Helper.
I'm confident that I can scratch together the HTML Helper to return the  image/anchor thingie.

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#selectMe').change(function ()
        {
           alert("changefunction called");
           alert('#'+$(this).val());
           alert($(this).val());
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX request to get the image information from the server:

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
       $.ajax({
           url : '<url-of-html-helper>',
           type : 'get',
           data : { selectMeVal : $(this).val() },
           success : function (serverResponse) {
               //if you server response is the HTML of the image then you can just add the serverResponse to the DOM
               $('#some-container').html(serverResponse);
           },
           error   : function (jqXHR, errorText, c) {
               //if an error occurs, handle it here, like re-run the request, or show a message to the user
           }
       });
    })
});
```

If instead of outputting the HTML for the image in your server-side code, you could just pass a source for the image and update an image already in the DOM (or create a new one via JavaScript). I generally try to limit the data that comes in via AJAX requests (it's always good to have your responses be less than 1500 bytes so it fits in a single packet, most of the time).

Comment: You have introduced a new "variable" Ajax which I am not ready to address. I have just written an adequate HTML Helper as cited in the original question to receive the value which I now have correctly popping up in an alert from  JQuery.           Once again the hopefully simple question was how to get this (now displayed in an alert) value to my HTML helper such that it may do its dance -- find the image related to this now selected categoryID---form up the image anchor markup whatever that stuff is and return my MvcHtmlString

Comment: @ChristianProgrammer Yup, that's what AJAX is for. Loading content without forcing a page-refresh. AJAX stands for: Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. Meaning that it executes without blocking other code from running, like a `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

Comment: @ChristianProgrammer If you add `data : { selectMeVal : $(this).val() },` to the AJAX call then you will be appending a GET variable named `selectMeVal` set to the value of the select element. This way you can pass the selected value to your Helper, then have the Helper output the necessary image data. Anything output by your Helper will be available to you in jQuery via the `serverResponse` variable in the `success` callback of the AJAX call.

Comment: As much as I appreciate your help I tried your suggestion. Perhaps I should mention again that I'm using .NET MVC. The success function & serverresponse seem moot to me as I have the value required to pass to my HTMLHelper from the change on the dropdown from JQuery. The HTML Helper's parameters appear to be the key here I cant leave it empty because the actual method operates on the passed int CategoryID to return the formatted markup containing the image-the url of htmlhelper for the ajax url parameter just makes no sense to me my HTML helper is hit at another portion of the page all thetime

Comment: Parameters are sent by `$.ajax()`, that's what the `data` property is for when you send the request. If you Helper is expecting the GET variable `CategoryID` then pass it that: `data : { CategoryID : $(this).val() }`, where `this` refers to the select element that has been changed. I don't have any experience with .net mvc but I have given this advise to people who do, and they got it to work. So maybe try searching for how to use jQuery with .net mvc to do a post-back.

Comment: http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/2009/11/29/ASPNET-MVC-DropdownList-PostBack.aspx   unfortunately the View Source is Dynamic not a specific model